# Using RackSpace cloudfiles with Paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, fog, rackspace

I've successfully uploaded, via Paperclip, images to the RackSpace cloudfile storage, and they appear correctly within subsequent webpages when I'm using the CDN url.

However, I can't figure out why Paperclip is not showing the files if I do not use CDN enabled cloud files.
Paperclip returns (via its 'url' method for the attachment) the more usual /attachments/fred/1/image/123.jpg path, however that results in a broken image as there is no actual file stored at that url - its in RS cloud file storage.

I'm not sure whether

a) Paperclip is supposed to give me a url to non-cdn location

b) Paperclip provides a url which results in it then responding at that url to provide the raw image data

c) Something completely different to a) and b)

If someone could please shed some light on what url I'm supposed to get back from Paperclip for non CDN enabled RackSpace stored files I think it would help steer me in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rackspace Cloud Files has the ability to download files without a CDN, but after researching it paperclip and fog do not currently support this.

Paperclip supports both CDN access as well as downloading files using a temporary url (sans CDN). I was going to suggest using a temporary url, however, the `get_http_url` method paperclip uses to retrieve this url isn't currently implemented for Rackspace.

I have created a fog issue to address this https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/2103.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I raised the matter with RackSpace also and they have confirmed that only access via CDN or the api is supported. I have therefore switched cloud storage to Amazon S3 instead.